# Why VSCode fails executing my main module in the new VSCode update?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

**********New post edition with a simple example********************

After the suggestion of Martineau, I tried a simplified example python program in the following. 
The background was that last week Vscode asked me to update to VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.31.1 in Win10.
So I did.
Then sometimes VSCode failed to execute my main module.
I tried to reinstall and uninstall vscode.  I also tried to modify the path variables here and there. 
But the problem is still there. 
Still I can execute the program OK purely in the console.

The simplified python program is the following.

```
print ("Here I am!")
```

The launch.json file is the following.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "vsCode Test ",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/pt.py",
            "args": [
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After I clicked the debugger button and then the right triangle button to execute the debugger, I always got the following screenshot which showed that nothing was executed.

[image: The console screen output after launching the simplified python program.]

I suspect that the new update has changed my settings in vscode. 
But I don't know where to reconfig vscode.

Your help will be deeply appreciated!

Thanks

Farn

****************Old post with a more complicate example!****************
dear all:

Last week Vscode asked me to update to VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.31.1.
So I did.
Then sometimes VSCode stopped to execute my main module.
The basic screen layout is the following.

[image: vscode screen image that shows the stalling before the 1st statement.]

VSCode basically stalled before the first statement and the first breakpoint.
But if I use Console to execute "python CnTaaD.py -L", the module (CnTaaD.py) executed correctly.

I tried several times and even reinstall, uninstall, used an older version of VSCode.
The stalling problem came on and off.
Then last night, VSCode always stalled before the first statement and the first breakpoint.
My friend helped me and guessed it is because the path to python interpreter is wrong now. 
But we tried to set the path variables here and there.
Nothing good happened.

The code of CnTaaD.py is in the following for your reference.
It calls another module.
Can anyone help by telling me how to reconfigure maybe VSCode so that I can resume the development ?

Thanks

---

```
from __future__ import print_function    # (at top of module)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import os 
    import sys 
    import CnUserManager 

    if sys.version_info[0] < 3: # Python 2 and 3:
        print ("python 2.x")
        #  to execute the file, type in the following command in powershell: 
        #  % python CnTaaDPackage.py build_ext --inplace
        import future        # pip install future
        import builtins      # pip install future
        import past          # pip install future
        import six           # pip install six
    else: 
        print ("python 3.x")
    root = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    # print ("realpath of __file__ is ", root)
    root = os.path.dirname(root)
    root = os.path.dirname(root)
    sys.argv.append(root)
    # print ("sys.argv = ", sys.argv)
    CnUserManager.CnUserManagerClass(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Try executing a super simple script—like `print('hello world")`—and see if you can get it run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I created a new workspace and attached the materials in the second part of the post.  
The stalling problem is still there.  The only print ("Here I am!") is not executed.

Comment: Then I suspect you're right about the path to the python interpreter being wrong. There are questions/answers here regarding how to configure which one VSCode uses—so search for those.

Comment: Thanks!  I just editted the post with the simplified example python program.  Any help that shows the links to appropriate pages will be appreciated deeply.  
For example, shall I change the configuration in Win10 or in VSCode ?  
Where ?

Comment: But should it be the case that VScode told me that the interepreter was not found if the interpreter path was incorrect ?
Moreover, I never changed the system path variables in the update.

Comment: This VSCode [help article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_pythonpath) may help.

Comment: Sorry that I still need make it a little bit clearer here. 
Do you mean that the problem is still vscode did find the interpreter in the debugger mode ?
I was thinking that maybe vscode did not find my python program.

Comment: I kind of solved the problem.
Basically, I removed the "RedirectOutput" option from the "debugOptions" in launch.json.  Somehow, the older version the redirection is to the console in the debug screen.  But now I am not sure where it is to. 
In fact, there are three consoles in VSCode, internal, integrated, and external.  Can someone enlighten me which is which ? 
I checked some related pages.  But vague explanations are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved the problem. 
Basically, I removed the "RedirectOutput" option from the "debugOptions" in launch.json. Somehow, the older version the redirection is to the console in the debug screen. 
But now I am not sure where it is to.

In fact, there are three consoles in VSCode, internal, integrated, and external. 
I will appreciate it if someone can enlighten me which is which ? 
I checked some related pages. But vague explanations are found.